# Call a method from an action

Tags: php, controller, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have a question class with an $id property and a getId() method. I also have an index action in the controller in which I wish to display the number of answers to that question.

```
class questionActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {          
        $q_id = $this->getQuestion()->getId();

        $this->answers = Doctrine_Core::getTable('answer')
                                                ->createQuery('u')
                                                ->where('u.question_id = ?', $q_id)
                                                ->execute();
  }
```

In my indexSuccess template:

```
<?php if ($answers) : ?>
  <p><?php echo count($answers) ?> answers to this request.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, this results in an Error: call to undefined method.

If I assign the value of $q_id manually, everything works perfectly.

How can I assign it with a call to the method getId() from the action? Should that call even be in the controller?

Comment: Can we see the method `getQuestion()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive that error because getQuestion() is not implemented in the controller.

I will assume you are passing the question id as a GET parameter.

In this case you could try something like:

```
  class questionActions extends sfActions {

    public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
      $q_id = $request->getParameter('question_id');

      $question = Doctrine_Core::getTable('question')->find($q_id);

      $this->answers = Doctrine_Core::getTable('answer')
        ->createQuery('u')
        ->where('u.question_id = ?', $question->getId())
        ->execute();
    }
```

Or better

```
class questionActions extends sfActions {

  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $q_id = $request->getParameter('question_id');
    $question = Doctrine_Core::getTable('question')->find($q_id);
    $this->answers = $question->getAnswers();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I think the fatest way is to call directly the query with the question id parameter (if your parameter in the url is `id`:

```
class questionActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    // redirect to 404 automatically if the question doesn't exist for this id
    $this->question = $this->getRoute()->getObject();

    $this->answers  = $this->question->getAnswers();
  }
```

Then you can define an [object route](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/05#chapter_05_object_route_class), so you won't have to check if the question exists for a given id, it will be the job of symfony itself.

```
question_index:
  url:     /question/:id
  class:   sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: Question, type: object }
  param:   { module: question, action: index }
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    sf_method: [get]
```

Then, when you call an url `/question/23`, it will automatically try to retrieve the question with the id `23`. If this question doesn't exists it will redirect to 404.